Hey I have a 2001 TTR 250 I tried to switch the battery and now nothing turns on at all?
The battery is brand new and charged there was a spark when I first installed it and then I got nothing at all after and not even the light will turn on what is it? Is it a fuse or a wire came loose?

What was wrong with the bike that prompted you to change the battery?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd suspect you need to re-seat the battery connections at the battery. Make sure they are clean before you do so.

What is the voltage reading across the battery terminals? Obviously it can't hurt to check the fuse.
